# Spring hibernate mysql can not fetch the data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my mysql database I have a table,named:-**file_upload**
table structure is ;-

I have stored picture in this table..Now I want to fetch the image..
So,I have:--

```
@Table(name = "file_upload")
public class ProfilePic {


      private long id;
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] data;

        --setters and getters with @Column annotation---

        public ProfilePic(BigInteger userId) {
            super();
            this.userId = userId;
        }
}
```

my dao class  is:--

```
    public ProfilePic FetchImage(ProfilePic profilePic) {
String hql = "select data from  ProfilePic  where userId = :userId1 ";

        logger.info( profilePic.getUserId());

        Query query =  (Query) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("userId1", profilePic.getUserId());


            return (ProfilePic) query.uniqueResult(); 
        }
```

But I am getting error:---

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4
```

why??where is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error said that Your query returns 4 rows , that this user has 4 rows in your **file_upload** table so `query.uniqueResult()` doesn't return unique result so change `query.uniqueResult()` to `query.List()`

use `query.uniqueResult()` when you guarantee 100% that your query will return only one single result

I don't know if you need to get all the ProfilePic objects associated with that user id or not but you can get the list and choose the one you want

```
 public ArrayList<ProfilePic> FetchImage(ProfilePic profilePic) {
        String hql = "select data from  ProfilePic  where userId = :userId1 ";

        logger.info( profilePic.getUserId());

        Query query =  (Query) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("userId1", profilePic.getUserId());


            return (ArrayList<ProfilePic>) query.List(); 
        }
```